# Distribute Android TV version with different package name

Tags: android, google-play, android-tv

I want to distribute two version of my app on Play Store, one for mobile devices and another one for Android TV. Those version have different packages name, I've been investigating and I think I have two options:

- Upload mobile version and habilitate Android TV, will I be able to upload the TV version with different package name or it should be just one apk working for mobile and TV?
- Create one app for mobile and another one for TV on Play Store, it won't be a problem since packages are different but for the TV mobile screenshot are needed, aren't they?

PS: I have notice that some apps like Netflix, Youtube and Prime Video have different packages name for mobile and TV version

Answer (score 0):

Each Play Store listing is unique based on package name/ID. **Google recommends a single app that supports mobile and TV with the same package ID. If they actually need to be separate APKs but can still be the same package ID, they can still be under the same listing.**

You *can* create two separate listings if the package IDs are not the same, but that creates a few problems for you. You noted one, which is that TV screenshots are only shown to TV devices, so you'd be displaying mobile screenshots for both listings on the web. Another is that you'll split your ratings and metrics, which can both be used to impact your search placement.

Most apps that have separate listings are apps that had a TV version in the very early days of Android supporting TV. Back then, the console didn't let you easily manage multiple variants of an APK.

For further info, you can see https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks